# Can I check which the previous activity was, Android?

Tags: android, if-statement, android-activity

I can reach activity C from two different activities, A and B. Activity C has one button. I would like to check if I went to C from A or to C from B. If I went from A to C, I would like the button to do one thing and if I went from B to C, I would like the button to do another thing.

Is it possible to check which the previous activity was?

Something like this...

```
else if (id == R.id.action_button) {

if (previosActivity == A) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);  
}

else if (previosActivity == B) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Include a flag in the extras bundle of the intent you use to launch `activity C`. The flag will either indicate `FLAG_A` or `FLAG_B`. Check for these flags in activity C and carry on accordingly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you go to **Activity C** form any of the activities, you can pass an `extra` through the intent. Then you can then retrieve that `extra` in **Activity C** and use it as desired

**Eg.**

When you go **from A to C**:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class); //'this' is Activity A
mIntent.putExtra("FROM_ACTIVITY", "A"); 
startActivity(mIntent);
```

When you go **from B to C**:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class); //'this' is Activity B
mIntent.putExtra("FROM_ACTIVITY", "B"); 
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Now in **Activity C**, you retrieve this:

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
String previousActivity= mIntent.getStringExtra("FROM_ACTIVITY");
```

Then you can use

```
if (previousActivity.equals("A")){...}
```

or

```
if (previousActivity.equals("B")){...}
```

As in your question.

Comment: Welcome. Do read Android documentation about how to pass data between Activities and Fragments, that will be helpful to you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an immediate way to do that but you can look in the `Intent` that was used to start the `Activity`.

For example, you can add an extras field to the `Intent` that launched Activity C.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
i.putExtra("Key", "Value");
```

Then in Activity C you can look in it by using `getIntent().getExtras().getString("Key")`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add information to the Intent in Activity A and B, then read that information in C.

In A and B:

```
public static final String KEY_ACTIVITY_NAME = "KEY_ACTIVITY_NAME";

Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityC.class);
intent.putExtra(KEY_ACTIVITY_NAME, activityName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in C:

```
if (getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_ACTIVITY_NAME) == "A") {
    //Do something
} else if (getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_ACTIVITY_NAME) == "B" {
   //Do something else
}
```